# Issues after downgrading to 16.04 from 17.04

Tags: home-directory, partitioning, downgrade

I had Ubuntu 17.04 and decided to go back to 16.04 as it had lot of stability issues. Upon uninstalling 17.04 and installing 16.04 the installation was successful, but the home directory and boot partition changed to a normal media partition and the root partition itself changed to home. I think this is a major bug!

Hence I'm reporting this issue.

Comment: Downgrading is such an arduous task!... It's better to you reinstall it from zero. You should preserve home partition and format root partition. Take note of which partitions are actually root and home. I suggest starting the live-usb Ubuntu and open each one to make sure o that.

Comment: Thanks @Redbob. I'm gonna reinstall. But may I know why this is happening? Is that a bug or something?

Comment: It's not really supported, more like a custom workaround which causes alot of errors. So not really a bug rather than an unsupported workaround.